# x86 assembly printing issue

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-16

For a class project I have to write a program that prints the reverse of an entered string. (I already submitted it, so I'm not asking for my homework to be done or anything, but I'm just curious as to why this is happening) I have a working version, but I'm a bit confused on my output. For a bit of background, I'm writing it in DOSBOX's debug command. My code is as follows:

```
MOV  AX,2000   ;set data segment 
MOV  DS,AX 
MOV  SI,1000   ;point to storage location 
MOV  AH,1      ;read command / 108 WAITFORLF TOP  
INT  21        ;read one char into AL (this is 21 Hex in debug) 
CMP  AL,0D     ;test for line feed 
JE   115       ;if line feed exit loop 
MOV  [SI],AL   ;save character to array 
INC  SI        ;increment byte array pointer to save next char  
JMP  108       ;JMP TO WAITFORLF TOP 
DEC  SI        ;on the first iteration it would print out one character too high (out of range), so decrement SI to point to last character entered
MOV  AH,02     ;WRITELOOPTOP 
MOV  DL,[SI]   ;get byte for write command 
INT  21        ;write to monitor 
DEC  SI        ;decrement SI to get next character
CMP  SI,1000   ;if SI is at start of data, end the loop
JNE  116       ;JUMP TO WRITELOOPTOP if not at beginning of data
INT  3
```

I thought this would work fine, but it would miss the very first character entered. I didn't think much of it, so I changed `CMP SI,1000` to `CMP SI,999`. This works fine, but now it also prints out a bunch of newline characters at the end. I'm just wondering why this would happen? I thought since it was missing the first character, allowing it to iterate just one more time would fix this (which it did), but it printing a bunch of newlines is what's confusing me.

Here's a screenshot from the first version (where it misses the first character), with the input being abcde:

[image]

And here it is when I changed it to fix that (also with the input abcde):

[image]

I'm also a bit confused on why I had to DEC SI once before entering the write loop. It was printing out the next character in memory, out of range of what was entered, but I'm wondering how it would even get there? Since SI is never incremented after a newline character is entered, shouldn't it just be left off at the index of the last character entered? Just trying to get a better understanding of what's going on. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with DOS system internals but your logic (apart from the system) works fine with `cmp si, 999`. Since it didn't work out well, try `cmp si, 1000; jne` *before* `dec si` not after.

Comment: You need to `dec` before printing the first character because you `inc`ed after storing the last character.

Comment: Oh, for my first comment, you also have to erase the `dec si` at the end and move the `WRITELOOPTOP` label at `dec si`.

Comment: Are all numbers here hexadecimal? If so, `1000-1` is `FFF`, not `999`. You're looping about 1600 times more than intended. Side note: `0D` is Carriage Return, not Line Feed.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, this is Debug input; Debug always reads numeric literals as hexadecimal. (My Debug clone [defaults to hexadecimal too](https://pushbx.org/ecm/doc/ldebug.htm#exprliteral) though it allows entering different bases too. Eg `mov ax, 3FF` is the same as `mov ax, (#1023)` for lDebug's assembler.)